# Raise event from user control inside repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, repeater

I have a user control that raise an event and I want to catch in other place.

In aspx I have;

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptMarcas" OnItemDataBound="rptMarcas_OnItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <uc1:FabricanteArbol runat="server" ID="treeMarca"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In aspx.cs

```
protected void rptMarcas_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Albero_dll.FABRICANTES fab = (Albero_dll.FABRICANTES)e.Item.DataItem;

        App_Componentes_FabricanteArbol tree = (App_Componentes_FabricanteArbol)e.Item.FindControl("treeMarca");
        tree.cargar(fab);
        tree.OnSelectedNodeClicked += new EventHandler(OnSelectedNodeClicked);
    }
}
```

In the user control;

```
public event EventHandler OnSelectedNodeClicked;
if (OnSelectedNodeClicked != null)
{
    CatalogoChangedEventArgs eCat = new CatalogoChangedEventArgs(e, SesionManager.posCatalogo, irPagina);
    OnSelectedNodeClicked(this, eCat);
}
```

But always `OnSelectedNodeClicked` is null.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue, though i need you to fix few things or tell me exact context.

```
Albero_dll.FABRICANTES fab = (Albero_dll.FABRICANTES)e.Item.DataItem;
```

e.item.dataitem will be the instance of your usercontrol so Albero_dll.FABRICANTES should be replaced by your user control name.

App_Componentes_FabricanteArbol tree = (App_Componentes_FabricanteArbol)e.Item.FindControl("treeMarca"); is wrong and will not work

Comment: Hi @Soner Gönül, thank for your answer. 

I only have to add OnSelectedNodeClicked="MiOnSelectedNodeClicked" and all work right.

'<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptMarcas" OnItemDataBound="rptMarcas_OnItemDataBound">

    <ItemTemplate>
         <uc1:FabricanteArbol runat="server" ID="treeMarca" OnSelectedNodeClicked="MiOnSelectedNodeClicked"/>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>'